# Scroll function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do a menu that moves up and down when I move the scroll. I'm close to it but when it moves it jumps a bit, the movement of the menu (div right) is not smooth. Anyone knows how to improve it?

(Of course it should not move horizontally and could not overlap the content on the left. Please see the example live here:http://jsfiddle.net/67ZFe/)

THE JQUERY:

```
$(function(){

    $(document).scroll(function(){
        var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        $('#right').css('margin-top', (windowTop)  + 'px'); 
    });

})
```

THE CSS:

```
body {background-color: #f2f2f2;font-size: 13px;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
#wrapper {position: relative; margin:0 auto;width:700px;height:900px;background-color:#fff;}
#right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right:0px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: red;
}
#text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    width:400px;
    padding:40px;
}
```

THE HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="text"> </div>
  <div id="right"> </div>
</div>
```

I have an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/67ZFe/

Comment: Why not pure CSS solution?
#right {position: fixed, top: 0}

Comment: As everybody said, you should make it with css. But here is a playful one with animate, http://jsfiddle.net/67ZFe/4/

Comment: @ocanal: Yes the fixed position is a easy way and gets a smooth movement, but your solution is so clever, and the efect is really interesting. Really great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be better, and faster, to do this with a `position:fixed;` css attribute rather than with jQuery.

Comment: I had to make a few changes, including wrapping `right` in a containing div called `right-cont`

Comment: Your example overlap the text, because of your `padding-left: 500px;`.

Comment: The text is only 400px wide in his example.

Comment: It works perfect! I'm surprised, I thought that  "An element with fixed position is positioned relative to the browser window." But you get to be position in relation to the wrapper?

Comment: What I did was set the vertical positioning relative to the browser window, but did not specify any horizontal positioning. Therefore, it got the horizontally positioning from the wrapper. I'm glad it worked for you! Can you accept my answer?

Comment: This is fantàstic!. I give you just a point because I cannot give more. I have been hours trying things and you solve it fast and in a such simple and clean way.

Comment: @Wes: I have been looking to fixed position in W3c and everywhere in Google and I cannot find anyone who explains this. The rule is that in fixed position if you don't give top, left... it gets that from the parent div? Instead of creating a parent div and giving a padding right of 500 I just give #right a margin of 500 is that corect?

Comment: Giving #right a margin of 500px should work too. How you achieve your goal is really up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but wouldn't it be easier to use an element with fixed position instead of moving the element all the time?

When an element uses fixed position, its position is determined in relation to the browser window, instead of the page. So the menu will always be placed at a certain position in relation to the top for instance, even if you scroll the page.

Using fixed positioning will be much more smooth than using a JavaScript-solution.

I would use something like:

```
#right {
   position: fixed;
   top: 50px; /* Or whatever suits you */
}
```

Comment: If it is fixed it will move horizontally too and would overlap the content

Comment: @Nrc Allright, so it have to be positioned in relation to some other content on the page? In that case I believe your solution is as smooth as it is going to get.

Comment: @Nrc Not sure if you like it better, but you could do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/67ZFe/6/), so instead of a lot of flickering, the menu moves when the user stops scrolling basically.

Comment: you were right, the fixed position is the best option but I did not understand until I could see the complert solution that gave me Wes. Thank you anyway.